# Marker in the GeoJson Layer

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

When using the Data API to import GeoJson data, gmaps will automatically generate points for each feature and place them on the appropriate position on the map.

Unfortunately, when listening to the data events such as click, there doesn't seem to be a way to access the feature corresponding marker or is this feature not a marker?

This would be helpful, among other things, to easily show an InfoWindow on the marker position. I can fetch the geojson with JS and add in a loop each point as marker. But i think it a dirty solution.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The shape(e.g. marker) that has been created is not accessible, but the properties of the feature are accessible(e.g. the position of a Point) via the geometry of the feature.

Sample:

```
  var infoWindow=new google.maps.InfoWindow();

  //add lick-listener
  map.data.addListener('click', function(event) {
    //geometry of the feature
    var geo=event.feature.getGeometry();
    //when it's a point
    if(geo.getType()==='Point'){
      //create the anchor where the infoWindow will be opened
      var anchor=new google.maps.MVCObject();
      anchor.setValues({//position of the point
                        position:geo.get(),
                        //offset  (0,-height of the marker)
                        anchorPoint:new google.maps.Point(0,-40)});
      //some content
      infoWindow.setContent('marker@'+geo.get().toUrlValue());
      //open the infowindow
      infoWindow.open(this.getMap(),anchor)
    }
  });
```